# iOS API - different between NSURLConnectionDelegate vs NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone explain to me what is the different between `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol.

for example, when i write such code in my viewDidLoad.
`[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:_request delegate:self];`

then, do i need to to add `<NSURLConnectionDelegate>` in my class interface declaration or both  `<NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>` to it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` has functions to deal with data, whereas `NSURLConnectionDelegate` has functions that are related to notify you about success or failure of your connection. You would most likely need both of these.

For more info, you can refer to Apple's [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html) documentation.

Comment: JFYI: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate page also says that "If you are using NSURLConnection as part of Newsstand Kit on iOS, you should also implement the methods in the NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate protocol."

Answer (score 0):

The `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol defines methods common to the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` protocols.      Delegates of `NSURLConnection` objects should implement either the data or download delegate protocol (including the methods described in this protocol).
`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` conforms to NSURLConnectionDelegate. The `NSURLConnection` class works in tandem with three formal protocols: `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, and `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate`. 
You need to add both of them.